# Using write access in Open command in TCL

Tags: tcl, pipeline

How can i use write ('w') and read ('r') access while using command pipeline in `open` command in TCL.

when i do something like :

```
set f1 [open "| ls -l" w]
```

it returns a file descriptor to write to , say `file1`.

Now I am confused how can I put this file descriptor to my use.

PS : My example might be wrong, and in that case it'd be ideal if answer includes a programming example so that it'll be more clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the key things you can do with a channel are write to it (using `puts`), read from it (using `gets` and `read`), and `close` it. Obviously, you can only write to it if it is writable, and only read from it if it is readable.

When you write to a channel that is implemented as a pipeline, you send data to the program on the other end of the pipe; that's usually consuming it as its standard input. Not all programs do that; `ls` is one of the ones that completely ignores its standard input.

But the other thing you can do, as I said above, is `close` the channel. When you close a pipeline, Tcl waits for all the subprocesses to terminate (if they haven't already) and *collects their standard error* output, which becomes an error message from `close` if there is anything. (The errors are just like those you can get from calling `exec`; the underlying machinery is shared.)

There's no real point in running `ls` in a pure writable pipeline, at least not unless you redirect its output. Its whole purpose is to produce output (the sorted list of files, together with extra details with the `-l` option). If you want to get the output, you'll need a readable channel (readable from the perspective of Tcl): `open "| ls -l" r`. Then you'll be able to use `gets $f1` to read a line from the subprocess.

But since `ls` is entirely non-interactive and almost always has a very quick running time (unless your directories are *huge* or you pass the options to enable recursion), you might as well just use `exec`. *This does not apply to other programs.* Not necessarily anyway; you need to understand what's going on.

---

If you want to experiment with pipelines, try using `sort -u` as the subprocess. That takes input and produces output, and exhibits all sorts of annoying behaviour along the way! Understanding how to work with it will teach you a lot about how program automation can be tricky despite it really being very simple.